# Angular2 - Modals with Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I was wondering if anyone can see why the "ng-control" for the form does not work inside my Modal component for Angular 2.

Here is the error that I get:

```
No provider for Renderer! (NgControlName -> Token NgValueAccessor -> DefaultValueAccessor -> Renderer)
```

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Qtu6gM4XqxCBUPxIhhz?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This could be because the `ModalRef` class isn't decorated so dependency injection doesn't apply. As emphasized in this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4404#issuecomment-143920530), you need to have this to be able to inject. `Injectable` isn't for being injected into something but for injecting into itself.

**Edit**

I think that this answer could give you some hints since it seems to be the same problem: [Angular2 No provider for Renderer! (NgModel -> Token NgValueAccessor -> DefaultValueAccessor -> Renderer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606534/angular2-no-provider-for-renderer-ngmodel-token-ngvalueaccessor-defaultv).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry