# Angular2 No provider for Renderer! (NgModel -> Token NgValueAccessor -> DefaultValueAccessor -> Renderer)

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I custom modal of customModal.ts in [shlomiassaf/angular2-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal).
Specific, i add a input contain ngModel, it imported FORM_DIRECTIVES and directives.

The issue when run 'No provider for Renderer! (NgModel -> Token NgValueAccessor -> DefaultValueAccessor -> Renderer)'

Please help me resovle this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you show console log of project (plnkr.co/edit/o09cpitFihjZE2EpHNRE?p=preview) and resolve error?

Comment: You need to add the renderer within the list of providers you give to the `loadNextToLocation` method in the `DialogService`. See my answer for more details ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

- The corresponding provider isn't specified at the component or application level. I don't think that the problem because I already inject a `Renderer` without having specified it in its `providers` attribute or within the second parameter of the `bootstrap` function.

  Something like that:

```ts
    import {Component,Renderer,ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'child',
      template: '<div></div>',
    })
    export class ChildComponent {
      constructor(private _renderer: Renderer,
               private el: ElementRef) {
        (...)
      }
    }
```

- I think it would be rather because the class where the renderer is injected isn't decorated so dependency injection can't apply. As emphasized in this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4404#issuecomment-143920530), you need to have this to be able to inject. `Injectable` isn't for be injected into something but for injecting into itself.

**Edit**

After having a look at your code, it seems that you need to add the renderer to the list of providers you provide to the `loadNextToLocation` method. You could update the code of the `DialogService#open` method like this:

```ts
var otherResolved = Injector.resolve([
  provide(DialogRef, { useValue: dialogRef})
  provide(Renderer, { useValue: this.renderer})
]);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add in your component decorator

```
@Component({
  providers: [Renderer],
  ...
)}
```

Comment: It is still error. Could you show console log of project (http://plnkr.co/edit/o09cpitFihjZE2EpHNRE?p=preview) and resolve error?